# Frida - hook android native C++ api

Tags: frida

Say android mediaserver has below API:

```
$ nm --demangle --dynamic libmediaplayerservice.so  |grep setDataSourceAsync
0005c6f0 T android::NuPlayer::setDataSourceAsync(android::sp<android::DataSource> const&)
0005c008 T android::NuPlayer::setDataSourceAsync(android::sp<android::IStreamSource> const&)
0005c18c T android::NuPlayer::setDataSourceAsync(android::sp<android::IMediaHTTPService> const&, char const*, android::KeyedVector<android::String8, android::String8> const*)
0005c49c T android::NuPlayer::setDataSourceAsync(int, long long, long long)

$ nm -D libmediaplayerservice.so |grep setDataSourceAsync
0005c6f0 T _ZN7android8NuPlayer18setDataSourceAsyncERKNS_2spINS_10DataSourceEEE
0005c008 T _ZN7android8NuPlayer18setDataSourceAsyncERKNS_2spINS_13IStreamSourceEEE
0005c18c T _ZN7android8NuPlayer18setDataSourceAsyncERKNS_2spINS_17IMediaHTTPServiceEEEPKcPKNS_11KeyedVectorINS_7String8ES9_EE
0005c49c T _ZN7android8NuPlayer18setDataSourceAsyncEixx
```

Now I wish to hook the last one:

```
0005c49c T android::NuPlayer::setDataSourceAsync(int, long long, long long)
```

Below code will work but the API name is mangled:

```
var libname = "libmediaplayerservice.so";
var funame = "_ZN7android8NuPlayer18setDataSourceAsyncEixx";

Interceptor.attach(Module.getExportByName(libname, funame), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
      console.log("onEnter: call fun enter");
    },
    onLeave: function(retval) {
      console.log("onLeave: call fun leave");
    }
});
```

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to use demangled name just like below in javascript code:

   android::NuPlayer::setDataSourceAsync(int, long long, long long)
2. The first argument `int` is a file descriptor just like open returned value. how can I use this fd to dump the file to disk in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

> *1. Is it possible to use demangled name just like below in javascript code:*

You will need to bind with Python, use `send('mangle:' + func_name)`

In python's side - `on_message` extract the `func_name` and mangle using `subprocess` to execute `g++`

```py
def on_message(msg, _data):
    if msg['type'] == 'send':
        if msg['payload'].startswith('mangle:'):
            # mangle
```

```sh
echo "class android{ void setDataSourceAsync(int, long long, long long) {}};void setDataSourceAsync(int,long long, long long){} " |\
 g++ -x c++ -S - -o- |\
 grep "^_.*:$" | sed -e 's/:$//'
```

It's tedious work ><

> *2. The first argument int is a file descriptor just like open returned value. how can I use this fd to dump the file to disk in
>   javascript?*

You want to save every byte that goes into the `fd`?

To not interfere the app execution,
I suggest to use `dup2`, read from it and `send` to python's side or write to `sdcard`

```js
var fopen = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'fopen'), 'pointer', ['pointer', 'pointer']);
var our_fd = fopen('/sdcard/tmpfile');
var dup2 = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'dup2'), 'pointer', ['pointer', 'pointer']);
dup2(fd, our_fd);
// use same technique to read from our_fd
```